# How keep uninstall files inside uninstaller?

Tags: inno-setup

Has a any way to make the uninstall files (JPEG, DLL, PNG...) stay inside of the `unins000.exe`? If so, please show a code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not any way to do this.  The Inno uninstall engine cannot contain embedded files.

But on the other hand there's no particular need for it to do so either -- you can just install any files that it requires (into a subfolder of the app folder, if you want to keep things tidy).

The only real reason that the setup files are embedded into the installer is that it makes downloads easier.  The uninstaller doesn't have that excuse.

Comment: Actually with some creativity, there's a way. Se [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38336841/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl True, but the effort to do so typically outweighs the benefit.  It's simpler to just install the files.  Still, points for creativity. :)

Answer (score 5):

Inno Setup has no native support for embedding files into the uninstaller.

But with some creativity, you can embed the files into the code (in a form of some constant).

Unfortunately the Unicode Inno Setup is quite limited when dealing with binary data as it tends to try to convert everything to UTF-8. But after numerous tries I've ended up with some working code (with use of a PowerShell code invoked from [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/)).

---

Add this code somewhere to the front of your `[Code]` section:

```pascal
function CryptStringToBinary(
  sz: string; cch: LongWord; flags: LongWord; binary: string; var size: LongWord;
  skip: LongWord; flagsused: LongWord): Integer;
  external 'CryptStringToBinaryW@crypt32.dll stdcall';

const
  CRYPT_STRING_HEX = $04;

procedure WriteBinaryStringToStream(S: string; Stream: TStream);
var
  Buffer: string;
  Size: LongWord;
  L: Integer;
begin
  L := Length(S);
  SetLength(Buffer, (L div 4) + 1);
  Size := L div 2;
  if (CryptStringToBinary(S, L, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, Buffer, Size, 0, 0) = 0) or
     (Size <> L div 2) then
  begin
    RaiseException('Error decoding binary string');
  end;
  
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Buffer, Size);
end;  

function StreamFromBinaryString(S: string): TStream;
begin
  Result := TStringStream.Create('');
  WriteBinaryStringToStream(S, Result);
  Result.Position := 0;
end;

procedure LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(Bitmap: TBitmap; S: string);
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := StreamFromBinaryString(S);
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure SaveBinaryStringToFile(FileName: string; S: string);
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    WriteBinaryStringToStream(S, Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

#define FileToBinaryString(str FileName) \
  Local[4] = ExtractFileName(FileName), \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + Local[4] + ".pas", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command """ + \
    "Write-Host 'Generating code for " + Local[4] + "'; " + \
    "$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('" + FileName + "'); " + \
    "$s = '''' + (($bytes | foreach { $_.ToString('X2') }) -join '') + ''''; " + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -Value $s;" + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  Local[3]
```

---

And then you can use the `FileToBinaryString` [preprocessor macro](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=macros) to convert a file on compile-time (or more precisely, when pre-processing) to a hex string like:

```pascal
'4D5A50000200000004000F00FFFF0000B8000....'
```

On runtime, you use the hex string with some of the functions `WriteBinaryStringToStream`, `StreamFromBinaryString`, `LoadBitmapFromBinaryString` or `SaveBinaryStringToFile`.

---

So for example to load a bitmap to `TBitmapImage`, use:

```pascal
LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(
  BitmapImage.Bitmap, {#FileToBinaryString("C:\path\WizModernSmallImage.bmp")});
```

On compile-time, this gets converted to a code like:

```pascal
LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(
  BitmapImage.Bitmap, '4D5A50000200000004000F00FFFF0000B8000....');
```

---

To extract a DLL, use:

```pascal
SaveBinaryStringToFile(
  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\InnoCallback.dll'),
  {#FileToBinaryString("InnoCallback.dll")});
```

To use a DLL extracted on runtime, you have to use the [`delayload` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll&anchor=delayload):

```pascal
function WrapTimerProc(callback:TTimerProc; paramcount:integer):longword;
  external 'wrapcallback@{tmp}\innocallback.dll stdcall delayload';
```

---

*The pre-processor/Pascal compiler has a limit of about 100M characters for a string. Though you will actually first hit a [compile-time] memory limit of the PowerShell script for files larger than about 20-30 MB.  Though even for smaller sizes (larger than few MBs), the compile-time time performance of the PowerShell script is bad. The script can be optimized significantly though.*

*Due to the hex encoding, the size of the installer increases twice as much. This could be improved by using some more efficient encoding, like Base64 (`CRYPT_STRING_BASE64`). The code section is not even compressed too, comparing to files included with the `[Files]` section (not a problem for images as these are compressed already, but makes a difference with DLLs for example).*

---

*This solution was initially developed for the question [Inno Setup: Reading a file from installer during uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37552286/850848)*.

---

*The code requires the Unicode version of Inno Setup. With latest Inno Setup 6, it's the only version available anyway. Even if you use Inno Setup 5, you should not use the Ansi version anyway, in the 21st century. Though ironically, implementing this in the Ansi version would be way easier. See [my answer to Writing binary file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38617829/850848#38618255) for a use of the `CryptStringToBinary` that's compatible with both Ansi and Unicode version of Inno Setup. Though in the Ansi version you can actually do with a binary string, instead of a hex string.*