# Inno Setup Embed DLL into uninstaller

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

Is it possible to load DLL located inside the `unins000.exe` instead of a file system or `{app}` path?

I want to hide this DLL and load it only while uninstalling.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to embed files into the uninstaller (`unins000.exe`).

But it's possible, see my answer to [How keep uninstall files inside uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14847218/850848#38336841)

---

Another way to "hide" the DLL, you can just rename it to some non-obvious extension.

Or to go a step further, pack it for some archive format. You can use Windows `.cab` format for example. For that you have tools ([`extract.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/extract) and [`makecab.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/makecab) in all modern versions of Windows (XP and up at least).

Note that no matter what you try, there's no way to prevent the user from accessing the DLL (even if you embed it to the uninstaller). You can only make it hard.

Comment: I think a valid reason other than just hiding the DLL, would be that perhaps you want the uninstaller to be self-contained. For instance if the app directory was corrupted and the DLL deleted, as a user you'd not be able to uninstall the remaining files / registry entries.

Comment: But the uninstaller is the app directory too. So it would be corrupted too.