# Inno Setup uninstall progress bar change event

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there any event/function like `CurInstallProgressChanged` for progressbar with `CurProgress` and `MaxProgress` values in Uninstall form in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native support for this.

What you can do is to setup a timer and watch for changes in the `UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Position`.

The code may be like:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure TimerProc(
  h: LongWord; AMsg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; dwTime: LongWord);
begin
  Log(Format(
    'Uninstall progress: %d/%d', [
      UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Position,
      UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Max]));
end;

function SetTimer(hWnd: LongWord; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord;
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@TimerProc)); // every 100 ms
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6.*

*If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library (the code needs Unicode version of Inno Setup 5). But using an external DLL library from an uninstaller is tricky and has its drawbacks. See (yours) [Load external DLL for uninstall process in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36940506/850848). For another solution (better but more complicate to implement), see [How keep uninstall files inside uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14847218/850848#38336841)*