# Inno Setup - How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress at uninstaller?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to use this code: [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092779/how-to-show-percent-done-elapsed-time-and-estimated-time-progress)

But I have problems, because i use this code to the installer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging these two piece of code together:

- [Inno Setup uninstall progress bar change event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37027172/850848)
- [How to show percent done, elapsed time and estimated time progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20092779/850848)

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd: longword; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord;
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetTickCount: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  UninstallStartTick: DWORD;
  UninstallPercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  UninstallElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  UninstallRemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    UninstallStartTick := GetTickCount;
  end;
end;

procedure UninstallTimerProc(
  h: LongWord; AMsg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; dwTime: LongWord);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
  CurProgress: Integer;
  MaxProgress: Integer;
begin
  MaxProgress := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Max;
  CurProgress := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Position;

  if MaxProgress > 0 then
  begin
    CurTick := GetTickCount;
    UninstallPercentLabel.Caption :=
      Format('Done: %.2f %%', [(CurProgress * 100.0) / MaxProgress]);
    UninstallElapsedLabel.Caption := 
      Format('Elapsed: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - UninstallStartTick)]);
    if CurProgress > 0 then
    begin
      UninstallRemainingLabel.Caption :=
        Format('Remaining: %s', [TicksToStr(
          ((CurTick - UninstallStartTick) / CurProgress) *
           (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  UninstallPercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallPercentLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallPercentLabel.Left := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Left;
  UninstallPercentLabel.Top := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Top +
    UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Height + ScaleY(12);

  UninstallElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Left := UninstallPercentLabel.Left;
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Top :=
    UninstallPercentLabel.Top + UninstallPercentLabel.Height + ScaleY(4);

  UninstallRemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Left := UninstallPercentLabel.Left;
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Top :=
    UninstallElapsedLabel.Top + UninstallElapsedLabel.Height + ScaleY(4);

  SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@UninstallTimerProc)); { every 100 ms }
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library. Note the drawbacks of using extension DLL in the uninstaller described in the [question linked from the first question above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36940506/850848#36941766).*

[image: Uninstall times]