# Inno Setup - How to create a new uninstalling page in a custom uninstall page?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using this code [Custom Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415457/custom-uninstall-page-not-msgbox/%20%22custom%20uninstall%20page%20(not%20msgbox)). (See the answer of Fr0sT). I want to disable the original uninstalling page by a new inside the custom uninstall page. Is this possible?

Comment: By the *"disable the original uninstalling page"*, do you mean *"hide original uninstall window/form"*?

Comment: @martinprikryl hide the original uninstalling page and add new uninstalling page at custom uninstall form (TnewNotebook)

Comment: Why? It's hardly doable. Wouldn't it be better to modify the standard uninstall form for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe it would be better to modify the standard uninstall form, rather than trying to implement a new one from the scratch.

See my answer to [Custom Uninstall page (not MsgBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7415457/850848#42550055).

---

Anyway, to answer your question. Yes, with some effort this may be possible.

To hide the main window and display a custom one, do:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  CustomUninstallForm: TSetupForm;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    UninstallProgressForm.Visible := False;
    { Move the hidden form back to the screen }
    { in a hope that eventual error messages will appear on screen }
    UninstallProgressForm.Left := CustomUninstallForm.Left;
    UninstallProgressForm.Top := CustomUninstallForm.Top;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  { Move the form away, so that it does not briefly flash on the window before the }
  { CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall) is called }
  UninstallProgressForm.Left := -1000;
  UninstallProgressForm.Top := -1000;

  { Create a custom form and display it }
  CustomUninstallForm := CreateCustomForm;
  CustomUninstallForm.SetBounds(
    0, 0, UninstallProgressForm.Width, UninstallProgressForm.Height);
  CustomUninstallForm.Position := poScreenCenter;  
  CustomUninstallForm.Show;
end;
```

---

- I cannot tell, what happens, when an error occurs during uninstallation.
- To propagate the progress from the main form to the custom one, see [Inno Setup uninstall progress bar change event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37027172/850848).

Comment: First, thank you for answering my question. But, It's not what i asked. Is your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415457/custom-uninstall-page-not-msgbox#42550055

Comment: How come it's not what you have asked? So what did you ask? What is my answer missing?

Comment: I want to hide the original uninstall page and add a custom uninstall page, all from the Fr0sT code.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. There's no uninstall page in the Fr0sT code. There are just some custom pages. The video you have posted shows exactly [what my code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7415457/850848#42550055) implements. So what's wrong?

Comment: It seems that you have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). You want X (wizard-style **uninstall** form), you have picked Y (Fr0sT implementation of wizard-style **custom** form) as a bad way to achieve the X. I've shown you that, while using the Y to achieve the X is possible, it's a wrong way. And you should use Z instead (my code).

Comment: If you read the comments to the Fr0sT answer, you will see that he claims that Z is not possible, that's why he implemented the Y. Not because it's a good way, but because he could not find a way to implement Z (but I've shown that it's possible).

Comment: I asked about the posibility of hide the original uninstalling page and add custom uninstalling page to this code. Perhaps the acceptable answer to me is that can not do such a thing and i can do something better with your code? (Sorry bad english) http://stackoverflow.com/q/7415457/850848#42550055 (your answer)

Comment: Why do you want to hide the original form (it's not a page) and re-implement it? What is wrong with the original form? What functionality do you want to implement, that the original form prevents you from implementing? You still didn't explain this - So far you didn't ask for anything, that would be easier to implement using a separate form, rather than by modifying the original form - Actually quite on the contrary - Re-implementing the uninstall form from the scratch, while retaining all the functionality (particularly error handling), is nearly impossible.

Comment: Is it clear now? Is there anything you need to add to my answer?